# Generating a new Random GUID in the Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, guid

How I can generate a random new GUID inside of the Dephi IDE?

I am using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: In XE7, I had to switch to the Default key mapping to get this to work.

Answer (score 11):

Ctrl+Shift+G will place a new GUID at the current position in the editor.

It's formatted for use as an interface IID, i.e. with enclosing square brackets - [] - , but once you've got the GUID in the text editor you can do whatever you want with it - Copy/Cut it to the clipboard etc

Answer (score 3):

I had wondered why this didn't work for me, but now I found out that it depends on the selected keyboard-layout in the Delphi-Options (`Options`->`Editor-Options`->`Keyboard`).

With the `classic IDE` layout it really is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, but I usually use the `VisualStudio-Emulation` and there it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Default key shortcut for Get module in Jedi VCS (if anyone still use VCS today) is the same and must be cleared in Jedi VCS Settings. Otherwise GUID shortcut won't work.