# Delphi UUID generator

Tags: delphi, uuid

Does Delphi have anything built-in to generate UUIDs?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
program Guid;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
SysUtils;

var

Uid: TGuid;
Result: HResult;

begin
Result := CreateGuid(Uid);
if Result = S_OK then
   WriteLn(GuidToString(Uid));
end.
```

Under the covers `CreateGuid()` calls one of the various APIs, depending on the platform. For example on Windows, it nowadays calls `UuidCreate`.

Answer (score 39):

Also, if you need a GUID for an interface declaration, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> in the code editor to insert a GUID at the caret.

Comment: That is a fast way to do, helped me a lot.

Comment: Be aware: the shortcut is dependent of the chosen keyboard layout in Delphi options (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45942091/2925238)

Answer (score 9):

Yes `TGUID`, see this example

```
program Guid;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
SysUtils;

begin
  WriteLn(TGUID.NewGuid.ToString());
end.
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using one of the latest version of Delphi, and include SysUtils, you can call `TGuid.NewGuid` to generate a new guid.

`NewGuid` is actually implemented in a helper class for TGuid ([TGuidHelper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.TGuidHelper)), which is declared in SysUtils.

This function calls the CreateGUID method (also in SysUtils and already mentioned in the answer by Mitch Wheat), which is actually a cross platform function that calls different libraries depending on the platform it runs on.

Comment: is this cross platform?

Comment: @MehmetFide - you can check yourself the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.CreateGUID

Comment: This was what I was looking for, but it didn't fully work. Since it is a class helper for TGUID, actually calling `TGuidHelper.NewGuid` doesn't work. You need to call `TGuid.NewGuid`. And that only works if you explicitly include SysUtils, because TGuid is system, but the helper is in SysUtils. I hope you don't mind that I updated the answer with this information.